# Automatic sum of 2 cells when filling into one cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make my sheet more automatic, I have this example of 2 rows:

```
 A  |  B
 -------
 40 | 40
 20 | 60
 30 | 90
 10 | 100
 -20| 80
```

Column B is sum of values of column A,
I want column B to be automatically filled when i put a value into column A, what function should I use?

I was trying with basic SUM, but when i tried to apply it on whole row it looked like:

```
 A  |  B
 -------
 40 | 40
 20 | 60
 30 | 90
 10 | 100
 -20| 80
 40 | 120
    | 120
    | 120
    | 120
```

And row B was full of "120". I hope anyone can help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=scan(,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,a+c))
```

[image]